# using Schur's complement and Young's inequality to reduce matrix algebraic equation to LMI

Tags: matrices, control-theory, linear-matrix-inequality, matrix-analysis, schur-complement

This questions concerns the practical implementation of schur's complement and Young's inequality.

Consider the following

\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Z}} & \mathcal{O}\\
\mathcal{O} & \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{P}} 
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{Z} & \mathcal{O}\\
\mathcal{O} & \mathcal{I}_{n}
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{Z} & \mathcal{O}\\
\mathcal{O} & \mathcal{I}_{n}
\end{pmatrix} & \begin{pmatrix}
D_{11} & D_{12}\\
D_{21} & D_{22}
\end{pmatrix}\\
\begin{pmatrix}
D_{11} & D_{12}\\
D_{21} & D_{22}
\end{pmatrix}^T & -\mu \mathbb{I}_{q}
\end{pmatrix} + \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
\overline{B} \overline{K}\\
\mathcal{O}\\
\mathcal{O}
\end{pmatrix}}_{V^T} \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
\mathcal{O} & \tilde{B} & \mathcal{O}
\end{pmatrix}}_U + \begin{pmatrix}
\mathcal{O}\\
\tilde{B}^T\\ 
\mathcal{O}
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
\left(\overline{B} \overline{K} \right)^T & \mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O}
\end{pmatrix} \leq 0
\end{align}

Now to avoid any bilinear coupling between terms, the young's inequality is used, as given by

\begin{equation}
X^T \hspace{1mm} Y + Y^T \hspace{1mm} X \leq \dfrac{1}{2} \hspace{1mm} \left( X + S \hspace{1mm} Y \right)^T \hspace{1mm} S^{-1} \hspace{1mm} \left( X + S \hspace{1mm} Y \right)
\end{equation}

where $S$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix. To apply the inequality, we use $S = \dfrac{1}{2} \mathbb{I}_n$ for the term $\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{Z} & \mathcal{O}\\
\mathcal{O} & \mathcal{I}_{n}
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{Z} & \mathcal{O}\\
\mathcal{O} & \mathcal{I}_{n}
\end{pmatrix}$ and $S = \epsilon \mathbb{Z}$ for the term $V^TU+U^TV$. Now, the intent is to use the young's inequality and convert the above algebraic equation in LMI using Schur's complement. I am unsure of the proper way and cannot reduce the equation to the requisite LMI. Given: $\mathbb{Z}$ is a $n \times n$ symmetric positive definite matrix.

Can someone walk me through the subsequent steps?

Comment: Which variables are known and which variable do you want to solve for?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen So the unknown variables are $\mathbb{Z}$, $\overline{K}$ and both $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Z}}$ $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{P}}$ are a function of $\overline{K}$. I assume you are asking this to figure out which block matrix is use for taking the schur's complement, right? For me, I think, as long as I understand the methodology, it does not matter which you take as known or unknown.

Comment: I assume that $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Z}}$ and $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{P}}$ are a linear function of $\overline{K}$?

Comment: @KwinvandeeVeen indeed... Thanks for the time :)

Comment: Why do you want to apply Young's inequality to $V^\top U+U^\top V$? Namely it is already linear in the unknowns.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen you are correct. I cannot believe that the paper I am reading has so many mathematical errors. I expected more. That is why I am questioning my conclusion and hoping somebody can point out why they did what they did.

Answer (score 2):

The only term that is not linear in the unknown variables is the quadratic term in $\mathbb{Z}$, so it might be easier to replace that with another variable and add another inequality

$$
\mathbb{Z}^2 \leq \mathbb{X}, \tag{1}
$$

such that the initial in equality can be written as

\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Z}} & \mathcal{O}\\
\mathcal{O} & \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{P}} 
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{X} & \mathcal{O}\\
\mathcal{O} & \mathcal{I}_{n}^2
\end{pmatrix} & \begin{pmatrix}
D_{11} & D_{12}\\
D_{21} & D_{22}
\end{pmatrix}\\
\begin{pmatrix}
D_{11} & D_{12}\\
D_{21} & D_{22}
\end{pmatrix}^\top & -\mu\,\mathbb{I}_{q}
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
\overline{B} \overline{K}\\
\mathcal{O}\\
\mathcal{O}
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
\mathcal{O} & \tilde{B} & \mathcal{O}
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
\mathcal{O}\\
\tilde{B}^\top\\ 
\mathcal{O}
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
\left(\overline{B} \overline{K} \right)^\top & \mathcal{O} & \mathcal{O}
\end{pmatrix} \leq 0, \tag{2}
\end{align}

which is linear in all variables. One can then use Schur's complement on $(1)$ which allows us to rewrite it also as an LMI

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
I & \mathbb{Z} \\
\mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{X}
\end{pmatrix} \geq 0, \tag{3}
$$

with $I$ an $n$ by $n$ identity matrix, $\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}^\top > 0$ and $\mathbb{X} = \mathbb{X}^\top > 0$.

So the combination of $(2)$ and $(3)$ should be equivalent to your initial inequality and are all LMI's.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...but my intent is to do it using Young's inequality, as I have pointed to in the question.

Comment: @Zero but why do you specifically want to use Young's inequality?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I actually think I do not need to use Young's inequality. like the methods you proposed, I was directly able to convert the inequality into an LMI without it. But there is this paper I am reading where they insist on it, which i was hoping someone can help me with.

Comment: @Zero Maybe adding more variables to an LMI would make it more computational to solve and more sensitive to numerical inaccuracies. I do have to note that I do not have much practical experience solving LMI's, so this is just speculation.

Comment: Appreciate it, I too am beginning to dig deeper into the numerical aspects of solving LMI rather than just using tools. I plan to try to solve these equation in different forms including the way you suggested, to see if makes any difference in any respect or not.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen, may I ask where I can find a reference for this formulation of the Young's Inequality?