# Reference to this Young Inequality for matrices

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system, semidefinite-programming, linear-matrix-inequality, young-inequality

In this post:
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3267556/using-schurs-complement-and-youngs-inequality-to-reduce-matrix-algebraic-equat) I saw the usage of this Young Inequality:

$$X^TY+Y^TX\leq \frac{1}{2}(X+SY)^TS^{-1}(X+SY)$$

With S any symmetric positive definite matrix. As far as I understood this could help to avoid bilinear terms in sdp programming if $X$ and $Y$ are the unknowns.
Where I can find a reference about this inequality?
Or a proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the reference for this refinement of the Young Inequality:

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7524904/